# Where can I find a house or apartment or any other residence in Chiclayo(Perú)?

Tags: accommodation, peru

Hi im trying to find an aparment or house in Chiclayo to rent but the Internet portals aren't too reliable. Anyone knows where I can found a reliable site to check house or aparments?
Thank you.

Comment: what about airbnb or similar sites ? they seem to give out several results. or are you looking for something else ?

Comment: Why are the internet portals unreliable? Is there an inherent difficulty using these websites in Peru, similarly as looking for hostels in Iran? Or is it just a question of not many results showing up in the search?